# Setting Canvas Children Property without ItemsControl ItemsSource Binding Property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Is there any means to set Canvas Children Property without ItemsControl ItemsSource Binding Property?

In order to keep separated my view from viewmodel, I have to bind the items.
I have used the the canvas as a designer from 'CodeProject'

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part2.aspx

I'm using a canvas for drag-and-drop purposes. It works well when I work manually inside the canvas.
Which means I add and remove the child items using

```
myCanvas.Children.Add(userControl);
myCanvas.Children.Remove(userControl);
```

But if I load my usercontrols at run time, they are loaded just as views.

```
<s:Canvas  AllowDrop="True" >

   <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=userControls}">

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>                        
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <s:Canvas Background="Transparent"/>                                
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>                                
                <s:ControlItem Content="{Binding Path=MyView}"></s:ControlItem >
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle> 

    </ItemsControl>

  </s:Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there aint. (Except manually clearing and adding...)

Answer (score 0):

Ummm yeah just draw items inside the canvas? :)

```
<Canvas>
   <TextBlock Text="I'm Child #1" />
   <TextBlock Text="I'm Child #2" Canvas.Top="50" />
</Canvas>
```

Or you can always do it in code-behind

```
myCanvas.Children.Add(myTextBlock);

foreach(var someControl in SomeControlList)
    myCanvas.Children.Add(someControl);
```

**Edit**

I see your update and have no idea what you're asking. If you want to drag/drop items onto a Canvas, you are better off adding/removing items from the `ItemsSource` than manually adding/removing items from the Canvas. Simply adding/removing them from `myCanvas` will not update the collection in your `ItemsSource`

I would recommend taking a look at [Bea Stollnitz's article on dragging/dropping databound  Items](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53). This means you would keep the `ItemsControl` you have now, but when you drop an item on top of the `Canvas` it adds the DataItem behind that object to the `ObservableCollection<MyDataItem>` that you call `userControls` (I don't like this name because it suggests that the data items contain UI items, which should not be the case)